# How to make Constructor Expression in SPRING (Criteria)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make it in my repository like this:

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT NEW example.NameAndDescription(task.name, task.description) FROM Task as task")
    List<Task> findAll();
}
```

But I've got an error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [example.NameAndDescription] [SELECT NEW example.NameAndDescription(task.name, task.description) FROM server.entity.Task as task]

My class:

```
public class NameAndDescription {

    String name, description;

    public NameAndDescription(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your `NameAndDescription` class is in the `example` package which is immediately off the classpath root?

Comment: @Naros, Oh!!! Many Thanks))) Now it works! You are great!